Aggregation query $sum in mongodb
I have 1 problem that needs to be solved. So i have a fake data in mongodb like this :
const db = [
  { id: 1, parent_tweet_id: null, content: 'hehhehe' },
  { id: 2, parent_tweet_id: 1, content: 'Reply hahahaha' },
  { id: 3, parent_tweet_id: 1, content: 'Reply muamuamua' },
  { id: 4, parent_tweet_id: null, content: 'bla bla bla' },
]

So i expected after run query like this :
// expected
const expected = [
  { id: 1, parent_tweet_id: null, content: 'hehhehe', total_reply: 2 },
  { id: 2, parent_tweet_id: 1, content: 'Reply hahahaha', total_reply: 0 },
  { id: 3, parent_tweet_id: 1, content: 'Reply muamuamua', total_reply: 0 },
  { id: 4, parent_tweet_id: null, content: 'bla bla bla', total_reply: 0 },
]

I am trying use Aggregation like this:
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$parent_tweet_id",
      total_reply: {
        $sum: 1,
      },
    },
  }
]

But I'm not getting the right results :
const notExpected = [
{ id: 1, content: 'hehhehe', total_reply: 2 },
{ id: null, content: 'Reply hahahaha', total_reply: 3 },
]

Can some one help me this???. It took me 2 days!!!!

What do you want as output.please clarify more.
Do you want to push your data by grouping or only sum of total_reply?

so i want the output is like const expected, not CONST notExpected

If you want
const notExpected=
[{ id: 1, content: 'hehhehe', total_reply: 2 },
{ id: null, content: 'Reply hahahaha', total_reply: 3 }]
as your output.
you can simply do
[
{$group:
{_id: '$parent_tweet_id',data:{$push:{$mergeObjects:{id:"$_id",content:"$content",total_reply:"$total_reply"}}}}}
]


No, you understand wrong. I want the result is const expected, not const notExpected. My english is bad, so i try to described this problem

Perform a self $lookup and perform $count in the sub-pipeline.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "parent_tweet_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$count": "cnt"
        }
      ],
      "as": "total_reply"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "total_reply": {
        "$ifNull": [
          {
            $first: "$total_reply.cnt"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

If your reply is in a recursive nature, you can use $graphLookup to get all children(i.e. replies to reply). Use $size to get the count.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$id",
      "connectFromField": "id",
      "connectToField": "parent_tweet_id",
      "as": "total_reply"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "total_reply": {
        "$size": "$total_reply"
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

so i should try one, right ?. Hmm, which is best of performance???

@ThuyNguyen It depends on your actual dataset and use case. If your reply is not recursive in nature, just use the $lookup.
